# vba issue with merging of cells with the same data in three columns into one row

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I wrote a macro, in which I need to merge the same triples of data (in three columns) into one row and count the rows, in which there were these triples occured. I wrote this code, but it counted the rows incorrectly. I also have a header in this worksheet's two first rows.

I have already tried this code, but it doesn´t count correctly:

```
Dim rw As Long
Dim lr As Long

lr = Rows.Count

For rw = Rows.Count To 3 Step -1

    If Cells(rw, 1).Value2 <> Cells(rw - 1, 1).Value2 And _
       Cells(rw, 2).Value2 <> Cells(rw - 1, 2).Value2 And rw < lr And _
       Cells(rw, 3).Value2 <> Cells(rw - 1, 3).Value2 And rw < lr Then

         Cells(rw, 4) = Application.Count(Range(Cells(rw, 4), Cells(lr, 4)))
         Cells(rw + 1, 1).Resize(lr - rw, 1).EntireRow.Delete
         lr = rw + 1
    End If

Next rw
```

This is my entire sheet:

> Date;            Critical;              Raw;               "SFG;
>
> 12/04/2019;           Y;                147833;           594673
>
> 12/04/2019;           Y;                147833;           656555
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           147833 ;        780319
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           147833;            842201
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           147833;             904083
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           147833  ;        965965
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           147833  ;        1027847
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           147833  ;         1089729
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           151753 ;          1151611
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           151753;              1275375
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           151753 ;           1337257
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           151753 ;           1399139
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           151753   ;         1461021
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           151753     ;       1584785

I want to get this:

> 12/04/2019;   Y;           147833   ;      8
>
> 12/04/2019;   Y;           151753  ;       6

Answer (score 0):

- Seems like you want to group by the first three columns and aggregate by counting.
- Save a copy of your workbook before running (just in case). Code below assumes your data is on a worksheet called `"Sheet2"` (change to whatever it is called in your case).
- Instead of looping over individual rows, we use some helper columns (if you have data after column D, it may get overwritten by the helper columns) -- and then filter by the values in those helper columns.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub GroupByFirstThreeColumnsAndCount()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        On Error Resume Next
        .ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("F3:F" & lastRow)

            ' Add groupByKeys
            .Formula = "=A3&""|""&B3&""|""&C3" ' Newer versions of Excel have TEXTJOIN. Use instead, if you have it.

            ' Add total count
            .Offset(0, -1).Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & .Address & "," & .Cells(1, 1).Address(rowabsolute:=False) & ")"

            ' Add cumulative/expanding count
            .Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & .Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(1, 1).Address(rowabsolute:=False) & "," & .Cells(1, 1).Address(rowabsolute:=False) & ")"

            Dim rangeToFilter As Range
            Set rangeToFilter = .Offset(0, -1).Resize(, 3)
        End With

        rangeToFilter.Value2 = rangeToFilter.Value2
        rangeToFilter.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(rangeToFilter.Rows.Count + 1, rangeToFilter.Columns.Count).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>1"

        Dim rowsToDelete As Range
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rowsToDelete = rangeToFilter.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not (rowsToDelete Is Nothing) Then rowsToDelete.Delete
        rangeToFilter.AutoFilter

        .Columns("F:G").Clear
    End With
End Sub
```

Gives expected output I think:

[image: Macro output]